# Принцип организации обработки запросов в Django REST

Tags: python, django, http, django-rest-framework

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять принцип организации обработки запросов в Django REST. 
[Вот здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/38730/), например, объясняются основы

> ```
>     GET /book/ — получить список всех книг
>     GET /book/3/ — получить книгу номер 3
>     PUT /book/ — добавить книгу (данные в теле запроса)
>     POST /book/3 – изменить книгу (данные в теле запроса)
>     DELETE /book/3 – удалить книгу
> ```

С этим понятно - стандартные запросы. Но как получить книгу с названием "название1"? Как удалить книгу с таким же названием? Т.е. как добавить фильтр? Как добавить свой метод, который будет вызываться, скажем, по `/book/3/status` и возвращать статус конкретной книги? Причем так, чтобы не перекрыть стандартные методы, описанные выше. Как это реализовать на Django REST? И вообще возможно ли это?

[Вот здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/181988/) рассказывается про принципы web-API в целом И есть пример такого запроса

> ```
> GET /dogs?color=red&state=running&location=park
> ```

Пытаюсь воспроизвести: `GET /book/` возвращает список всех книг. Но и `GET /book?id=1` также возвращает список всех книг

В тестовом примере у меня в urls.py:

```
url(r'^book$', MyAPI.as_view())
```

В views.py:

```
class MyAPI(mixins.UpdateModelMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = Book
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated
    ]
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return BookSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by('order')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Как добавить фильтр?**

У вас есть метод, возвращающий все книги - `GET /book`. Логично, что искать книгу по названию нужно среди всех книг. Согласно этому http://habrahabr.ru/post/181988/ руководству подобные параметры нужно передавать за знаком вопроса. Значит в url'e должно получится `GET /book?name=название1`, а в методе, отвечающем за отдачу всех книг, нужно проверить наличие параметра `name` и отфильтровать выборку из базы по его значению:

```
if request.GET.get('name', None):
    Book.objects.filter(name=request.GET.get('name'))
```

То же самое с удалением, отличается только http метод.

**Как вернуть статус?**

Если вы будете отдавать статус книги по `/book/3/status`, то как тогда будет выглядеть url для получение и статуса, и цены книги? 
Согласно все тем же рекомендациям из этой http://habrahabr.ru/post/181988/ статьи вам не нужно делать по методу на каждое возвращаемое поле.
Нужно за знаком вопроса указать какие именно данные о книге необходимо вернуть: `/book/3?fields=status,price`. В коде точно так же получаем необходимые поля `request.GET.get('fields')` и отдаем клиенту только то, что он попросил.